# use jQuery.matchHeight from Angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am trying to set elements to the same height using jQuery.matchHeight. I call the function from an Angular directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('matchHeight', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    var linkFunction = function(scope, element) {
      $timeout(function() {
        angular.element(element).matchHeight();
      });
    };

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linkFunction
  };
}]);
```

The matchHeight plugin and jQuery are included in index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    all head stuff
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="row usps">
      <div class="col-sm-4 usp-block" ng-repeat="block in content.marketing" match-height>
        <a href="{{block.link_url}}" class="thumbnail">
          // Rest of html
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/matchHeight/dist/jquery.matchHeight.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/directives/matchheight.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the height is not set although the directive is being applied to the element.

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery.matchHeight plugin](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height) will set all the items in an array to the height of the tallest element in that array.

the match-height directive is applied to a single element. Because there is no array, the height is not set on the element.

Moving the directive to the parent element in the DOM and adding the class *equal* to the child element(s) gives the array needed to set the height.

```
<div class="row usps" match-height>
  <div class="col-sm-4 usp-block equal" ng-repeat="block in content.marketing">
    <a href="{{block.link_url}}" class="thumbnail">
      // Rest of html
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the service I apply the matchHeight function to all elements with the class *equal*

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('matchHeight', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    var linkFunction = function(scope, element) {
      $timeout(function() {
        angular.element(element).find('.equal').matchHeight();
      });
    };

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: linkFunction
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, guys.
https://github.com/christopher-weir/AngularJs-MatchHeight
this custom directive is working fine. Also, codebase is pretty simple you can tweaks as your project need.